# multiply selectors with input values in jquery

Tags: jquery, multiplication

my calculation is not working quite well. Maybe you can help me:

```
  <input id="count" min="1" value="1" class ="txtMult form-control" type="number" name="txtEmmail" />
  <input type="text" value="250"  class ="txtMult" name="txtEmmail"/>
  <span class="multTotal">250</span>

<select class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">multiply with 1</option>
<option value="2">multiply with 2</option>
</select>

<span id="grandTotal">250</span>
```

And here the Javascript:

```
$(function(){
                $('input').change(function(){
                    var p=$(this).parent().parent()
                    var m=p.find('input.txtMult')
                    var mul=parseInt($(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()).toFixed(2)
                    var res=p.find('.multTotal')
                    res.html(mul);
                    var total=0;
                    $('.multTotal').each(function(){
                        total+=parseInt($(this).html())
                    })
                    $('#grandTotal').html(parseInt(total).toFixed(2))
                });
            })


$(window).load(function(){
$('select').change(function() {
   $("#grandTotal").html($('select').val()*$('.multTotal').html())
});
});
</script>
```

So I would wish that the #grandTotal is always changing right. If select for example "multiply with 2" and after change the value of my "#count" the "#grandTotal" should automatically display the right number. I am so confused with the calculation. Maybe you see it clearer. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the issue wrong calculation or change event is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/6fLk8w8a/1/

updated js

```
 $(function(){
                $('.txtMult').change(function(){
                    alert("work");
                    var p=$(this).parent().parent()
                    var m=p.find('input.txtMult')
                    var mul=parseInt($(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()).toFixed(2)
                    var res=p.find('.multTotal')
                    res.html(mul);
                    var total=0;
                    $('.multTotal').each(function(){
                        total+=parseInt($(this).html());
                    })
                    alert(parseInt(total).toFixed(2));
                    $('#grandTotal').html(parseInt(total).toFixed(2));
                });
            })



$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
    calcVal();
});

function calcVal(){
    alert($('select').val()*$('.multTotal').html());
   $("#grandTotal").html($('select').val()*$('.multTotal').html())
}

// call on document load
calcVal();
```

Your binding was not proper, use proper class.

Answer (score 0):

while calculation in javascript side, you have to parse as int or float.

You can use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

```
var i = parseInt( $('select').val()) * parseInt( $('.multTotal').html())
$("#grandTotal").html(i);
```